# Free PAAS / IAAS Service

Tags: linux, web-apps, python, cloud-service, hosted

Is there a hosting service that matches all of these criteria:

- free for personal use (or free trial)
- no credit card required
- support of any server-side language (python 3 / django would be cool, but not mandatory)
- static IP address
- outbound web traffic (very small rate)

Ideally :

- integration with github (ci/cd) or ssh access ?

I'm not looking for a fast or reliable server, a slow one will do.

I was so far using pythonanywhere, but it doesn't allow async http requests so I'm looking for an alternative.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not services – so this seems off-topic. For details, you might refer to our Meta post on [Are hosting recommendation requests on-topic?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/675/185)

Comment: Thank you for your warm welcome. I'm really struggling to find a forum where I can get an answer to this question, so please help to find a way to get this question answered by the community. I've already been rejected out of various forums and didn't get an answer, so any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I'd really like to tell you where it fits and where you'd get good recommendations – but unfortunately, I don't know, sorry.

Comment: there's app engine, but standard plan (that has free quota) doesn't have ssh, the other one that has ssh (flexible plan) doesn't have free quota XD
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas
the cons is you're locked to appengine stack (there's alternative in the past: appscale, but the page on their website no longer exists)